# How can I run a PHP script multiple times and pass in arguments to it?

Tags: php, recursion, exec

I've got a directory of files, and I'd like to pass these filenames as arguments to a PHP script that will execute until there are no more files in that directory.

What I've got is something like this:

```
$files = scandir('./directory');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    exec ('script.php?filename=' . $file);
}
```

I can't get it to work. I'm not positive that using **exec** is the best option, but I'm not sure I can get it to work using include/require (or can I??).

Comment: If the code in your `script.php` can be run as a function, you could just include it and pass the appropriate variables into it as parameters. For your exec, does the code run but not get the parameter, or does it just not run?

Comment: Using `exec` is almost never the "best option". Why not just make `script.php` redirect back to itself with a different filename? I'm not sure of your exact use-case, but another possible method is using AJAX which allows you to send requests to a PHP script from JavaScript.

Comment: @droopsnoot - My exec does not run at all. As for **script.php**, I need to run the entire script and turning that whole page into a function isn't feasible.

Comment: Do you need to preface the command line with php to run it from the command line, as in `php script.php?filename=test.txt`, or will file association rules tell the server how to run it? I haven't used it from the command line.

Comment: also GET parameters are a HTTP concept, they wont work with CLI

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone - If I don't want to run from CLI (just through the browser), do you have any recommendations?

Comment: show contents of `script.php`, I suspect a simple closure would work to isolate scope pollution, just pass `$filename`: https://3v4l.org/pnB7F

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - Your solution worked. Thank you!!! How can I 'accept' your answer...for some reason I can't see how to do that on SO.